# KQL - Data Extraction

Tags: azure, kql, azure-sentinel

I would really appreciate if you could help me with a query that I would need to my report. This is my query:

SecurityAlert
| where ProviderName contains "IPC"

and the result is:

[image]

I would need to extract just the AadUserId from Entities but I'm not sure how since I'm still new to the KQL language.

I would be very grateful if you could advice.

Thank you very much.

I expect to extract AadUserID from my query.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let SecurityAlert = datatable(ProviderName:string, Entities:dynamic)
[
    "IPC", dynamic([{"AadUserID":"Dummy"}])
];
// Solution starts here
SecurityAlert 
| where ProviderName contains "IPC"
| project tostring(Entities[0].AadUserID)
```

| Entities_0_AadUserID |
| --- |
| Dummy |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1XOu2rDQBAF0H6/4rKVBMZKLZPCxCncGINxJVRMpIm9YR9idxQjEv97Nn6RTHnnDnOqCjtyg2X0JIQDe44kJvg5NkEwUBSEd8iRkYIdLxtlWbDjboxGpqXlXHm%20nAu9WS62MXyanuOGHNdJovGHGV69GDGc6n7y5ExXqkYhj15vX/QMt7RovvSS%20n3iuF7pWq9G5yZ9bkvVLlSVqTcCkmRYwpEjq/8S9Y3Tb4y/DHTBCxmfrv9yZ4jhgzuBhKuwuAObp3b%20IJQ/VOHjUh8BAAA=)

---

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let SecurityAlert = datatable(ProviderName:string, Entities:dynamic)
[
    "IPC", dynamic([{"AadUserID":"Dummy"}])
];
// Solution starts here
SecurityAlert 
| where ProviderName contains "IPC"
| mv-expand Entities
| project tostring(Entities.AadUserID)
| where isnotempty(Entities_AadUserID)
```

| Entities_AadUserID |
| --- |
| Dummy |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WOTU8CQQyG7/MrmjntJsje13ggwoELISGeCDF1p0LNfGWmC2zU/%204IuGqP7/u0fZoGNuiiJTAoCHvylFA4%20CmsgkDEJBBeQQ4EOdj%200ihLAhvq%20sQyzCwV5OGyLvhiqVqncGRDaYWO2iyJ/X4CCy8sTLk1g0fHXa22Csro5fpRT%20CWVtt3PUPzlCkt57rV8965QX/uarW7V01RvSlAliKW4UCJ1H8T9QGn7xj%20akAXvCD7fP1XGHe8o3NEb0azEsYU3qgTkHDVrn666ShVj/c5%20yDkogwj9vyLfQE2%20qcjWAEAAA==)

---

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let SecurityAlert = datatable(ProviderName:string, Entities:dynamic)
[
    "IPC", dynamic([{"AadUserID":"Dummy"}])
];
// Solution starts here
SecurityAlert 
| where ProviderName contains "IPC"
| mv-apply Entities on (summarize make_set(Entities.AadUserID))
| project set_Entities_AadUserID
```

| set_Entities_AadUserID |
| --- |
| ["Dummy"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WOu07DQBBF+/2Kq61sKcS9EUVEKNJEkSKqKLIGe0gW9mHtjoPM499ZQmLBlHPPzD1VhS253jI6EsKBPUcSE/wc6yDoKQrCM+TISMEO50RZFmy5HaKRcWE5I3fnc6Eny8UmhpPpOK7JcZ0kGn+Y4cGLEcOp7kZPzrSl2ink0avNvZ7hsi12H3pB3WPiuFrqWi8H50b9tS/V/lZVWfWigCRZLOHIkdV/E/WJt581/mqgDV7I+PTblxl3uqG+t+Mkhvy1SLmPonlnOHrlJrEU13w+eZVlvu9jeOFWkJHmijQT8g1c5nsPVgEAAA==)

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for the answer and apologies because I did not explain myself properly. I actually need to extract the complete AadUser ID. AadUserId":"a4bcee3-b480-45cd-923a-c3605f45d21c","Type":"account". I soulh do this for every alert. How sould I modify the script? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi. Please accept the answer and post a new question, this time with a sample data (you can use datatable, like I did) + required results. Per StackOverflow guidelines, please avoid images.